# Matching text between symbols and contain certain word

Tags: regex

Could someone help me to do this with regex?
mach the text between "<" and ">" and contain "word1" or "word2" or "word3", etc..

Answer (score 1):

[Something like that?](https://regex101.com/r/amahJ4/4)

`/(?<=<)[^<>]*?(?:word1|word2|word3)[^<>]*?(?=>)/`

Comment: There's a link to regex101.com on my post. It matches stuff within my sample text. Can you post the string that doesn't give you matches?

Comment: your formula works only if I replace < and > with words but I need match text between that symbols

Comment: I don't understand what you're saying. Please give a clear example of what you want to match exactly, with source text and desired results.

Comment: true... 
<p>this<br/><br/>is<br/> an <br/><br/>example<br/>lol<br/></p>

Comment: I want replace "is" and " an "  so become 
<p>this<br/>example<br/>lol<br/></p>